# Selenium - Find all elements of a web page

Tags: java, selenium, find, html, element

I am planning a tool in Java which would have a drop down containing all the elements of a web page. Is there any way I can read those into a data structure?

Comment: Hi.. are you able to develop the above tool?? Even am planning to develop the same tool.. need your inputs please..

Comment: It's still a WIP, but we are progressing.

Comment: Can you explain the summary of developing procedure??

Comment: It's a swing UI to develop scripts which invokes a javascript to execute those.

Answer (score 30):

Yes, there is a way.

Here is some pseudo-code:

```
List<WebElement> el = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("*"));

for ( WebElement e : el ) {
  add(e.tagName());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure I don't see the cssSelectors in this case. For instance, I tried for google.com, and I get these- Images
Maps
Play
YouTube
News
Gmail
More
Sign in

Comment: Any idea how to capture custom elements? Have tried using `execute-script document.all` but that still seems to return only standard elements

Comment: Will this also get the custom elements(elements/tags that are not default but created by the user, for example, <my-tag></my-tag>)?

Comment: yes it will. any Dom element. By.cssSelector("my-tag")

Answer (score 1):

non-pseudo C# version of above: (although I'm just displaying the results in a console

```
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> el = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("*"));
foreach (IWebElement elm in el)
{
    Console.WriteLine(elm.TagName + elm.Text);
}
```